# Storing passwords

Tags: swift, macos, security

I have an macOS application that allows the user to enter some sensitive data (a password) into an `NSSecureTextField`.
The password is however stored as a string in that `NSSecureTextField`, which makes it completely visible in memory.

My question is how easy is it for a macOS process to view another processes memory? Should I worry about the password hanging in memory?

Comment: Process isolation (including address space isolation) is just about the most important thing an operating system does, so you can imagine it's addressed with the most significant care. If a rogue process can read other process's memory, it's kind of already game over. Whether that's a tolerable risk for you to take depends on what this password protects, and how valuable it is.

Comment: @Alexander The password in my situation is of upmost importance. However, the only solution I can think of to avoid using Strings is to stop using a TextField and use a custom control

Comment: What exactly is your threat model? Merely typing a password would put it into the memory of the keyboard's micro controller, the USB HID driver of the OS, and probably several other places. If you're trying to be protected against an "attacker can read RAM" situation, a desktop computer like a mac pretty much gets disqualified

Comment: @Alexander I'm just trying to prevent against general cases I guess. But I suppose the only way to make it safer is to create a custom UI control that uses an array as its backing?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/4879.

Comment: Mac OS does not allow application to access memory of other application.

Comment: Is the password visible and editable? It isn't very difficult to replace keydown events with bullets.

Comment: You most probably don't need a custom control. It will be much easier for an attacker to get the password via other means (like phishing, social engineering) than to get it from process memory. Strong authentication is not about protecting the entered password at all costs.